# iPad Modal UIViewControllers position

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

How do I position this ViewController over the **detail view** modally? I want it to be right aligned so you can see the navigation portion greyed out.

```
[self.window addSubview:self.splitViewController.view];
MyModalViewController *modalvc= [MyModalViewController new]; //brevity
modalvc.modalInPopover = YES;
modalvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStylePageSheet;
modalvc.view.autoresizeMask = UIViewAutoresizeFlexibleRightMargin;
[self.splitViewController presentModalView:modalvc animated:NO];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I also checked in MyModalViewController if im setting the views mask and I am not, nor is it getting magic values from a Nib.

Adjusting the frame before the present (using modalvc.view.frame) does nothing.

Adjusting the frame after the present seems to yield crazy results, and I only really need it to be half a width over in landscape... portrait is normal behavior.

**edit**
the picture confused people so I took it out, I dont want the modal view to be the size of the screen, I want to keep it UIModalPresentationStylePageSheet but have its ORIGIN moved right so that it covers the detail view portion in landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and I ended up using a custom view controller that uses a background translucent view and a foreground opaque view that I am able to position anywhere I want by manipulating its frame. It's useful as a lightbox for videos and images.

Answer (score 1):

The `modalPresentationStyle` is what controls that.  You've set it to `UIModalPresentationStylePageSheet`, which sets the height to the height of the screen, and the width to to the width of the screen in portrait orientation, exactly as in your screenshot.

I think the only way to get full width in landscape is to use `UIModalPresentationFullScreen`.  See the [UIViewController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Comment: I am not sure if I conveyed what I really need. I need it to stay that SIZE but make it right aligned (UIViewAutoresizeFlexibleRightMargin) but thats not seeming to work.. its still in the center after getting presented